# Emacs mini-buffer command with parameter

Tags: emacs

I'd like to use the command to resize split windows via the mini-buffer. In the GNU documentation I found the description ([Resizing-Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Resizing-Windows.html#Resizing-Windows)):

```
Example: enlarge-window-horizontally size &optional horizontal.
```

If I type <kbd>M-x enlarge-window-horizontally</kbd> the window will get resized by one column. But it is not possible to add a number for the size in the mini-buffer, as on pressing spacebar emacs tries to complete the command.

Does someone know how to use the optional parameters in mini-buffer? Respectively how to resize a window by more than one column at once.

Thanks.

Comment: This confused me too. The help for `C-x ^` indicated that passing an optional non-nil argument to *it* would (also) result in a horizontal enlargement of the window. I couldn't get this to work: `C-u 1 C-x ^` to enlarge horizontally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing parameters to interactive command like this uses the [universal argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html).

You can enlarge the window by 10 columns by typing <kbd>C-u 10 M-x enlarge-window-horizontally</kbd>. You can change 10 to any integer. By the way, typing <kbd>C-u num</kbd> to supply a numeric argument works with all interactive emacs commands that expect an argument.

Note there is also a keyboard short cut: <kbd>C-u 10 C-x }</kbd>.
And to shrink the window: <kbd>C-u 10 C-x {</kbd>.

You can also specify numbers by typing holding down the meta key <kbd>M-10 C-x {</kbd>

Comment: universal-argument FTW! if the thing after it doesn't take an argument (or is just a character) it happens that many times. Otherwise, that is sent as the (only) argument to the command. A VERY useful thing to know about!

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is eval-expression.

`M-: (enlarge-window-horizontally horizontal)`

`M-:` will change the minibuffer to an eval prompt that lets you enter in a Lisp expression to be evaluated.